# How to match React Router path from right to left

Tags: javascript, react-router

Using React router (and more specifically [path-to-regex](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0) that it depends upon). I have the below URL structure where I need to extract both the ID and the slug from the URL and it works fine!

However, there are some URL's that have appeared in our data feed that have caused some problems:

```
<Route
    exact
    path="/:slug-v-:id/"
    component={({ match }) => {
        // http://example.com/this-is-a-url-v-42-12345/
        console.log(match.params.slug); // 'this-is-a-url'
        console.log(match.params.id); // '42-12345'
        console.log('It works!'); // 'It works!'

        // http://example.com/this-is-a-v-annoying-url-v-42-12345/
        console.log(match.params.slug); // 'this-is-a'
        console.log(match.params.id); // 'annoying-url-v-42-12345'
        console.log('It breaks :('); // 'It breaks :('
    }}
/>
```

The extra **-v-** that appears in the slug breaks the params. I would like to match the path in reverse, i.e from right to left, or have an alternative method if possible.

Comment: Why do you need to match in reverse as opposed to modifying your RegEx to account for one or more `-v-` sequences before the `:id`?

Comment: I could match the last occurrence if it was plain old regex but it's using path-to-regex. Unless I'm missing something in the docs. I don't need to solve it by "reversing" necessarily.

Comment: I don't have any experience with `path-to-regex` but per the docs, the `path` can be `An Express-style string, an array of strings, or a regular expression` so I assume you can use a "plain old regex."

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use 
path="/:slug/:id/"